# java groovy split array for csv output

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy, export-to-csv

Aim is to create a groovy script that will read from the database and export to a csv file.  I am using the apache commons csv writer. I have been working with this [javacode geeks - apache commons tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/)..

**This works** 
I have put here to help explain what I am trying to achieve.

```
fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);
csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

//Write a new student object list to the CSV file
for (Student student : students) {
   List studentDataRecord = new ArrayList();
   studentDataRecord.add(String.valueOf(student.getId()));
   studentDataRecord.add(student.getFirstName());
   studentDataRecord.add(student.getLastName());

   csvFilePrinter.printRecord(studentDataRecord);
}
```

**What Im trying to do In groovy/java.**

I have created a groovy script calls the DB ok.  I can make it iterate and loop over fine and prints the rows.  However I dont want to manually write all the 'student.getFirstName' student.getLastName etc calls. If I modify the query in the future it makes more work -- I just want to export it straight to csv having only modified the query.

Something like this is what I have so far..  I am unsure of the syntax etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat

CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);
csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

sql.eachRow("Select field1, field2, field3, etc FROM Student") {
    for( keyIndex  k ){
        List studentDataRecord = new ArrayList();
        studentDataRecord.add(k.value)
    }
    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(studentDataRecord);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are iterating with `eachRow`, each row is a `groovy.sql.GroovyResultSet` (strictly speaking, a `groovy.sql.GroovyResultSetProxy`). Since it does not implement `Map` interface, you cannot use `collect`, etc.

Therefore, there are several options:

***Get each field by name*** (the one you want to avoid)

```
sql.eachRow("select field1, field2, field3, etc from student") { row ->
   csvFilePrinter.printRecord([row.field1, row.field2, row.field3, ...])
}
```

***Get each field by number*** (I guess you don't like this either)

```
sql.eachRow("select field1, field2, field3, etc from student") { row ->
   csvFilePrinter.printRecord([row[0], row[1], row[2], ...])
}
```

***Use the underlying `ResultSet`***: get the number of colums and then build a `List`

```
sql.eachRow("select field1, field2, field3, etc from student") { row ->
    def record = []
    row.getMetaData().columnCount.times { record << row[it] }
    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(record)
}
```

***Use the `rows()` method***, that returns a `List<GroovyRowResult>` where `GroovyRowResult` implements `Map` and then you can apply `collect`:

```
def rows = sql.rows('select * from student').each { row ->
    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(row.collect { entry -> entry.value })
}
```